# Get javascript load calling stack

Tags: website, javascript

Is there some tool that will give me a load stack of the javascript files our web site loads? Our page is slow because of some javascript files load times being slow, but they're not file we're loading. So one of the file we're loading is loading them.

I need to find the call stack that leads to loading the slow files (on is on gdrive - not the fastest response ever).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Chrome DevTools (ctrl+shift+i). Here's screenshot of all javascript files (cache disabled) this page loads:

[image: Chrome DevTools (only JS enabled,cache disabled]

On the top you can see a timeline where i have selected an area of interest (white background). On the right side I hovered over requested file `pubads_impl_201812102.js` which reveals all the information how long the request needed with an [expanation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation) (scroll down and read "View initiators and dependencies").